# updating column in db table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an int id column that I need to do a one-time maintenance/fix update on.

```
For example, currently the values look like this:
1
2
3

I need to make the following change:
1=3
2=1
3=2
```

Is there a way to do this in one statement? I keep imagining that the update will get confused if say the change from 1=3 to occurs then when it comes to 3=2 it will change that 1=3 update to 3=2 which gives

```
Incorrectly:
2
1
2
```

If that makes sense,
rod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a sql case statement (something like this)?

```
UPDATE table SET intID = CASE 
WHEN intID = 3 THEN 2
WHEN intID = 1 THEN 3
WHEN intID = 2 THEN 1
END
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the assignments within an UPDATE statement (both the assignments within the SET clause, and the assignments on individual rows) are made as if they all occurred simultaneously.

So

```
UPDATE Table Set ID = ((ID + 1) % 3) + 1
```

(or whatever the right logic is, since I can't work out what "direction" is needed from the second table) would act correctly.

You can even use this knowledge to swap the value of two columns:

```
UPDATE Table SET a=b,b=a
```

will swap the contents of the columns, rather than (as you might expect) end up with both columns set to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually do it

```
DECLARE @Update Table (@oldvalue int, @newvalue int)

INSERT INTO @Update  Values (1,3)
INSERT INTO @Update  Values (2,1)
INSERT INTO @Update  Values (3,2)

Update Table
SET 
   yourField = NewValue
FROM  
   table t
   INNER JOIN @Update 
   on t.yourField = @update.oldvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've done stuff like this by creating a temp table (whose structure is the same as the target table) with an extra column to hold the new value. Once I have all the new values, I'll then copy them to the target column in the target table, and delete the temp table.